# What is the most flexible .NET based CMS software

Tags: c#, content-management-system

I am looking for a very flexible CMS. I want to use the CMS to create a comparison matrix. I have tried wordpress but could not figure out how to create a comparison matrix. Do you guys know of a very flexible CMS to create this kind of content?

Comment: Please don't ask questions like "What kind of program wrote this website cheezy.spam.website.I.want.to.drive.traffic.to.com."  It makes you look like a cheezy spammer who wants to drive traffic to your cheezy spammy website.

Comment: Why did you say the above statement. Please help me understand

Comment: @Luke101: You asked a question which was essentially "how can I make a website like this:" and provided a link to a website that has vacuum cleaner reviews.  That question is now deleted.  Please don't ask a question like that again.

Comment: That was a legitimate question. Why has that question been deleted. It would have answered many of my concerns. How do you suppose that I ask this question accurately without giving the link to the website?

Comment: @Luke101: That is an unacceptable question here.  If you cannot figure out a better way to ask that question that does not require people to click over to a vacuum cleaner website then you'll have to find another place to ask that question.  Besides, the question is off-topic for StackOverflow.  This is a website about *programming*, not about "which CMS should I use".  If you have further concerns, you can ask a question about this on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @Will: There are many CMS and off-topic questions here on stackoverflow. Why do you not delete them as well? The link was provided to give users a very clear explanation of my problem. Furthermore, there are many other questions on SO with links in them and very similar questions to mine about other CMSs and websites, but they are not being deleted.

Comment: @Luke101: You flag them and I'll close as off topic or, if the question smells like spam, delete it.  I'm just some slob that volunteers here as a mod; I am not responsible for examining each and every one of the *one point friggen five million questions* on here.  Hell, if I was, I'd quit.  Again, if you disagree, ask about this on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Umbraco](http://umbraco.com/) is a very flexible, .NET based CMS.

Comment: Haha, i was just typing the same thing.
Anyway, as said, Umbraco is indeed very flexible, especially the recently released versions with Razor syntax support =)

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Hehehehe, I wouldn't go that far - it's got its annoyances, but it's very flexible, too...

Comment: Okay, maybe just a demon - I can't decide which yet. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the old days DotNetNuke was a viable platform, but the underlying technology seems ancient compared to the new Orchard Project.

http://www.orchardproject.net/

While it is still very early, I would expect this to be the defacto CMS for many people.  It is just so architecturally robust and optimized to leverage the latest technologies in the .NET space.

Answer (score 0):

[DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) is by far the most popular. It has a large number of [open-source extensions](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/ExtensionsForge/tabid/824/Default.aspx) available too.